# Compiler optimization through subrange types

Tags: swift, range, compiler-optimization

I am investigating Swift and i would like to apply some of MacLennan's principles of programming languages on Swift.

However, i'm not getting his principle of "preservation of information" which states that the user should be able to represent information that the compiler will need. As an example subrange types are mentioned, which would "make it easier to optimize". How can the compiler do some optimizations based on subrange types (i.e. ranges in Swift) ? Is this optimization even applicable to Swift?

I tried to come up with some code examples (which are really bad), however, i'm wondering if this range information could really be used by the compiler to do some optimizations or if it is just a shorter way to do the same.

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
arr[1...3] = ["a", "a", "a"]
// Instead of
var arr2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
arr2[1] = "a"
arr2[2] = "a"
arr2[3] = "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting array values individually and doing it through ranges are two different operations. while changing array values through range may change it size, setting values through index left the array size untouched. e.g

```
var a = [1,2,3,4]
a[1...2] = [6,7,8] 
print(a) // result in [1, 6, 7, 8, 4]
```

this shows that subscript operation using ranges just replace range positions by values of the new array expanding the array if needed, what is different from setting array values by index.

Comment: Thanks, this was just some really bad code example i came up with. Do you know if The Swift compiler is able to do some optimizations in some cases where e.g. ranges are used? What did they mean with "make it easier to optimize"?